# Dragging file to 'select a file' dialog results in file transfer

Tags: macos, finder

I'm working with macOS for many years now, but lately, I noticed that when I try to select a file by dragging and dropping in the "file selection dialog", the file is transferred to the folder opened in the dialog instead of the dialog to navigate to the proper library and select the dropped file.

**I can't remember any change in my settings that caused this. How can I change it back?**

My machine:

- macOS Monterey  12.2.1
- MacBook Pro (14-inch, 2021)

Comment: Are you running the file selection dialog in Icon or in List view?

Comment: Icons, this is same as ever

Answer (score 1):

Same happened to me right after updating to MacOS Monterey. Annoying.

But there is a simple solution, the functionality is actually increased, by allowing two things:

- Drop the file or folder onto the **list of files** in the "select a file" window, then the file is MOVED
- Drop the file or folder onto the **toolbar** above the header of the file list, then the corresponding FOLDER IS OPENED in the list